Uncaught DOMException since migrating to Angular 13
I am using Bootstrap 4.6.2 with my Angular project. One of the components has a table with ngb-accordion. It all worked fine until I migrated the project to Angular 13.
Now, I'm getting the following error in the console when navigating to the page that holds the accordion. It doesn't prevent navigation from happening, and I'm still able to open/close the accordion. I just wish the error message would disappear:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '#4bdecde7-0564-475c-a160-655206d24c9e' is not a valid selector.
    at t._getPanelElement (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:347916)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:346729
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at qf.forEach (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:91610)
    at Nt._next (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:346704)
    at Nt.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:5045)
    at Nt.next (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:4286)
    at ae._next (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:3479)
    at ae.next (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:3253)
    at lP._next (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:181212)

I believe this is due to the Bootstrap version but I am not sure how to solve it. Here's an extract of my package.json for reference:
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^13.4.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "file-saver-es": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.12.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "source-map": "^0.8.0-beta.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.18",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.13",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"   }

Please help!

As anticipated, the issue was due to Bootstrap. I upgrated the following packages to make it work:
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.1.2",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
"bootstrap": "^5.3.0",

